# how to add multiple tables in hook_schema() in .install file while creating custom module?

Tags: database

Is it possible to add multiple tables in hook_schema() while creating a custom module? I have created a custom module with the help of Drupal entities. Will it be possible to store two different table in the modulename.install file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You definitely can!
In your hook_schema implementation, your first array key is the table name. You can add as many as tables in this array:

Ex:

```
function quotes_schema(){
  $schema = array();
  $schema['quotes'] = array(
    'description' => 'Base table for Quotes. Contains all submitted data from initial page.',
    'primary key' => array('qid'),
    'fields' => array(
      ...
     ), 
  $schema['quotes_access'] = array(
    'description' => 'Access tokens to quotes.',
    'primary key' => array('qid'),
    'fields' => array(
      ...
     ),     

    ...
  return $schema;
}
```

This will create both `quotes` and `quotes_keys` tables.

Comment: if i would like to add two tables and both are inter related then ??

Comment: They don't have to relate to other tables. Just make sure each table is a key in the $schema array.

Answer (score 3):

Or you just create your tables in phpmyadmin or whatever GUI or terminal you prefer and let [Schema module](http://drupal.org/project/schema)
do the rest , give it a try it will save you ton of time.

Comment: +1 I think it's good practice to know how hook_schema() works, but once you get it, you should definitely move along to Schema module, it will save loads of time when you're developing and trying stuff out.

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit to the number of table schemas defined in an implementation of `hook_schema()`. It is enough to see how many tables the System module defines in [system_schema()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.install/function/system_schema/7).